# Jquery Chrome animation issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://inspiredthinkinggroup.com/micro/

when clicking contact button on upper right, animation works fine in all other browsers,
but in chrome it's stuck in half way.it's completed when mouse pointer move from the button. This is only happens in chrome and can't figure out the issues,

```
$('.btnContact').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(".sliderHome").animate({ top: "-570px"},500);
        $(".contactUsPage").animate({ top: "0px"},500);
        $("#internalPage").animate({ top: "-570px"},500);
        $('.btnContact').addClass("contactSelected");
        $('.scrollnav').removeClass("selected");
        $('.internalTitle').hide(0);
        $(".logoCont h1").html("Overview for Simon Ward").fadeIn(300);
    });
```

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see a difference between Chrome and any other browser... Can you capture the issue with a screenshot?

Comment: this is happens when u click contact and keep ur mouse over contact button, without moving it else where.

Comment: Oh I see, the content slide gets stuck. I was looking at the button itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still couldn't find asolution for this, anyway i have found that it's some thing to do with the bg video. it's embedded using sw object. seems like chrome can't process both at same time.

Thanks for the help guys.!!

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly when you remove this part of code:

```
$('.btnContact').addClass("contactSelected");
$('.scrollnav').removeClass("selected");
$('.internalTitle').hide(0);
$(".logoCont h1").html("Overview for Simon Ward").fadeIn(300);
```

and leave only:

```
$('.btnContact').live('click', function(event) {
    $(".sliderHome").animate({ top: "-570px"},500);
    $(".contactUsPage").animate({ top: "0px"},500);
    $("#internalPage").animate({ top: "-570px"},500);
});
```

So try to do it in another way

Comment: Nope. it's still happening. i think it's something to do with the bg video, when i remove it it's working fine. it's weird. i am using swobject embed the video.